# docker runs images,but cannot get the response

Tags: docker, centos

the image runs successfully.But i can not get the response.

here is the run command.The boot-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar is just a simple SpringBoot project.

```
docker run -d -p 8888:8888 -v /usr/makoto/boot-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:/usr/makoto/boot-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar  --name makoto  java:8u111 java -jar /usr/makoto/boot-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

here is the curl command

```
curl -GET 127.0.0.1:8888/ttt
```

The problem has been solved.When use Centos in the vmware,docker runs successfully.

Anyway,I am grateful for your help.The reason caused this problem is still unknown.Welcome you write down your conjecture.I will test it one by one.

Comment: how did you run the container? please add the command here in the question body

Comment: @SeniorPomidor thanks your advice,i had add the command now.

Comment: according to your log the application started on 8888 port but hasn't mapped such as `/ttt`.  do you really have a /ttt mapping?

Comment: You attached two image files to the question; what are these?  Can you edit the question to include a [mcve] with enough source code (as text and not images; in the question directly and not behind links) to demonstrate the issue and show exactly what commands you're running?

Comment: @DavidMaze Forgive my naive way to take a question.I will use the code instead of the image next time.

Comment: @SeniorPomidorS It has the /ttt mapping.Now i change the development enviroment that  use the vmware.All problems are solved.

Answer (score 0):

It's simply because you are trying to curl IP 0.0.0.0:8888, You should curl localhost:8888 instead

```
curl -GET localhost:8888/ttt
```

if you want to call a container from the host you can use the localhost, 127.0.0.1 with the exposed port for the container.

Comment: could you provide me with the output for  ` docker exec -it makoto /bin/bash -c " curl -GET localhost:8888/ttt "`

Comment: could you try running the container specifying the host network using --network host option.


docker run --network host -d -p 8888:8888 -v /usr/makoto/boot-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:/usr/makoto/boot-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar  --name makoto  java:8u111 java -jar /usr/makoto/boot-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar @makoto

Comment: according from my test,the run command is right . Now i use the centos in the vmware,the problems are solved.Thanks for you help.